# ask set /p variable on a different line

Tags: batch-file, cmd, set

I've seen in batch code that you can ask for user input on a separate line or continue while asking or something. For example it would look something like this;

```
enter your name
name:_(input would be here)
enter name above
```

And the code might look like;

```
echo Enter your name
set /p /(continue) name=name:_
echo enter name above
```

Or maybe:

```
echo enter your name
(line 2)
echo enter your name above
set /p /line:2 name=name:_
```

Comment: I did look at that and I'm not the most experienced coder. I'm making a code for my mom's B-day on the fifth. But i do know most commands for batch (cmd).

Comment: oops sorry! did not mean to flag your comment i was just seeing what the window looked like... your comment is fine! sorry! ACCIDENTAL FLAG!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

cls
echo  enter your name
echo name: 
echo enter name above

rem Move cursor to one line below screen size,
rem you must adjust this value to fit your screen.
for /L %%i in (1,1,34) do echo/

rem Move cursor to screen home and hide timeout "Waiting..." message
for /F %%a in ('timeout /T 1 ^> CON') do rem

set /P "name=name: "
echo/
echo/
echo/
echo Name read: "%name%"
```

Further details at [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6760)