# Batch file: How can I have text after set /p?

Tags: batch-file, variables, text, cmd, set

I Discovered, not to long ago, that there was a script that uses set /p surrounded by text so that the output looked like:

```
Welcome to my code!
Please Enter your username
(Set /p was here)
>
More text
more text
```

Basically I assume that there is some way to have set /p not activate until after more text. So far I have:

```
echo Welcome to my code!
echo please Enter your username
set /p username=">"                     <This is what needs to be changed
echo Enter password
echo ">"
echo Enter Server IP
echo ">"
pause
```

Perhaps the set /p could be placed at the end of the script but told to activate up top? I've spent quite some time searching for this but I don't quite know what to enter, and thus, I am getting no results. thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest you try not to use variable names which are normally defined in the system, e.g. **`%username%`**.

Comment: they are entering their minecraft username :)

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445097/ask-set-p-variable-on-a-different-line) How would I customize that though? I do not understand what it is doing, and the set /p is ending up on the first line of the screen, replacing other text. Could you give me more information Aacini?

Answer (score 1):

You need cursor positioning for this.
Windows 10 in recent version does support ANSI Escape sequences.
Generating the sequence <kbd>esc</kbd> might be difficult depending on your editor.
Absolute cursor position is <kbd>esc</kbd>[y;xH

So printing an input form and then jummping to the position can be done this way:

```
@Echo off
Cls
echo Welcome to my code!
echo please Enter your username
echo ^>
echo Enter password
echo ^>
echo Enter Server IP
echo ^>
Echo: 
set /p nameuser=esc[3;3H
set /p password=esc[5;3H
set /p serverIP=esc[7;3H
pause
```

You've to replace `esc` with the escape symbol.
In Notepad++ you can enter the escape symbol by holding down <kbd>alt</kbd> and typing 027

Comment: For the escape symbol When I did that it gave me this ╧ and an error. Do you mean this: ^?   although that did not work either.

Comment: Could you per chance comment the symbol? Or give me a link to it or a picture? thanks.

Comment: Which exact Windows version and which editor?